# HasPrincipalKey() Equivalent for Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

EF Core allows me to create a foreign key relationship on a property that is not the primary key:

```
public class Foo
{
    // Primary key 
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Not primary key, but it does have a unique index.
    public Guid Uuid { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid FooUuid { get; set; }
}
```

EF Core with Fluent API

```
// Bar 
builder.Property(c => c.FooUuid).IsRequired();
builder.HasOne<Foo>()
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(c => c.FooUuid)
    .HasPrincipalKey(g => g.Uuid)
    .IsRequired()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

I can't find a equivalent to do this with EF6 and the fluent API.

Who can help me out :)?

Comment: Can't be done in EF6. EF6 relationships can only point to PK properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EF6 each entity has exactly one key.  But you are free to configure your entity key to map to any key in the database.  So you can make `Foo.Uuid` the entity key.

Comment: Thank you for your cormment. As Gert Arnold comments, my situation where Id is the primary key but Uuid is used for the foreign key is not possible. I will accept your comment, Thanks

Comment: “Primary Key” is a database concept.  EF6 doesn’t care which key you designate as the Entity Key.

Comment: I understand! But I mean that in my case `Id` is the primary key and `uuid` is a unique key used for foreign keys and such. This works in EF Core but not in EF6

Comment: Just to be clear, the `Uuid`  property can be configured as the Key in EF, even though the `ID` column is the "Primary Key" in the database.